# Cron job not auto runs inside a Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, cron

I have a LAMP container with supervisor.

I add a simple cron

```
* * * * * root /bin/date >> /var/log/cron.log
```

from my Dockerfile

```
ADD ./crons/test /etc/cron.d/test
RUN chmod 0777 /etc/cron.d/test
```

I start cron via supervisor with a `supervisor-cron.conf` like this:

```
[program:cron]
command=/bin/bash -c "cron -f"
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=2
```

Cron starts fine and stays up and running. The strange thing is that no cronjob is running automatically [as it should] but when I execute `docker exec lamp crontab /etc/cron.d/test` the cron job starts and works as expected.

Am I missing something? Everywhere I have read that cron jobs are executed automatically by cron.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**I solved it.**

I tried both setting them up in /etc/crontab and /etc/cron.d/ .

Cron didn’t auto-start the cron jobs .

However, when I run `docker exec lamp crontab /etc/cron.d/my_cronjob_file` all played nice. This made me suspicious , and then I read [this](https://kb.iu.edu/d/afiz) . So, after adding my_cronjob_file in the container [in the dockerfile] I added `RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/my_cronjob_file` . This essentially ‘installs’ the cronjob to the crontab table. [I don’t know the internals of cron/tab but that’s the gist I understood.] .

After that , the cron service comes up by supervisor and the cronjob runs like a charm.

Comment: Do never forget cron extects mode 0600 on my_cronjob_file. So:

**$ chmod 0600 /etc/cron.d/my_cronjob_file**

Otherwise you're gonna get something like: `Apr 14 04:21:05 hostname /usr/sbin/cron[2990]: (root) INSECURE MODE (mode 0600 expected) (crontabs/root)`

Comment: I thought it worked, but it's still not working for me. Cron service is not running at time of starting docker

Comment: if you want to run cron automatically just put `RUN cron`

Comment: could you please help me clarify whether your `my_cronjob_file` contains the user field after the time specification `* * * * *` in order for it to work? The standard way of defining cron jobs in `/etc/crontab` or any file in `/etc/cron.d` requires that the job has a username field after the time. But when a file is processed by `/etc/crontab`, the user field should not be added. I also found something [here](https://serverfault.com/a/976645/940850).

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with the bash file, due to the layered architecture of the Docker, cron service doesn't get initiated with RUN/CMD/ENTRYPOINT commands.

Simply add a bash file which will initiate the cron and other services (if required)

**DockerFile**

```
FROM gradle:6.5.1-jdk11 AS build
# apt
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install cron
# Setup cron to run every minute to print (you can add/update your cron here)
RUN touch /var/log/cron-1.log
RUN (crontab -l ; echo "* * * * * echo testing cron.... >> /var/log/cron-1.log 2>&1") | crontab
# entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
CMD ["bash","entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
service cron start & tail -f /var/log/cron-2.log
```

If any other service is also required to run along with cron then add that service with `&` in the same command, for example: `/opt/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh & service cron start & tail -f /var/log/cron-2.log`

Once you will get into the docker container there you can see that `testing cron....` will be getting printed every minute in file: `/var/log/cron-1.log`